# Question 4.56 from Nilsson and Riedel 8Ed Mesh Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, mesh-analysis

I need to solve this problem using meshes. I had no problem doing it by nodes but when I try to do it by meshes it doesn't match with the final answers. It asks the power from the 10 V source. From nodal analysis I found \$V_x=40\text{ V}\$, \$I_x=5\text{ A}\$, \$I_0=-18\text{ A}\$, power = 180 W.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the *included schematic editor* because **it puts part numbers** into the schematic.

Here's my rendition:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF5vzK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The four loops shown above are:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V} - R_1\cdot I_{1} - V_1 - R_2\cdot\left(I_{1}-I_{2}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} - R_2\cdot\left(I_{2}-I_{1}\right) + \left(V_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{X}}\right) - R_3\cdot\left(I_{2}-I_{3}\right)&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} - R_3\cdot\left(I_{3}-I_{2}\right) + \left(V_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{B}}\right) - R_4\cdot I_{3}&=0\:\text{V}
\\\\
V_{_\text{A}} + \left(V_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{A}}\right) - \left(V_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{B}}\right) - \left(V_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{X}}\right) + V_1 &=V_{_\text{A}} 
\end{align*}$$

We also know that \$I_4=-I_{_\text{B}}\$ and that \$I_{_\text{A}}=I_2-I_4\$ so we can also say:

$$I_{_\text{A}}=I_2+500\:\text{mS}\cdot V_{_\text{X}}$$

And we know that \$I_{_\text{X}}=I_3-I_2\$. So:

$$V_{_\text{C}}-V_{_\text{B}}= 2\:\Omega\cdot \left(I_3-I_2\right)$$

And we know that \$V_{_\text{A}}=-R_1\cdot I_1\$ and finally that \$V_{_\text{C}}=R_4\cdot I_3\$.

This gives us eight equations to solve for \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$, \$I_3\$, \$I_{_\text{B}}\$, \$V_{_\text{A}}\$, \$V_{_\text{X}}\$, \$V_{_\text{B}}\$, and \$V_{_\text{C}}\$.

Let's test it out. Using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
var('vx vb vc v1 r1 r2 r3 r4 i1 i2 i3 ia ib')
(vx, vb, vc, v1, r1, r2, r3, r4, i1, i2, i3, ia, ib)
eq1 = Eq( 0 - r1*i1 - v1 - r2*(i1-i2), 0 )
eq2 = Eq( 0 - r2*(i2-i1) + (vb-vx) - r3*(i2-i3), 0 )
eq3 = Eq( 0 - r3*(i3-i2) + (vc-vb) - r4*i3, 0 )
eq4 = Eq( va + (vc-va) - (vc-vb) - (vb-vx) + v1, va )      # relates va to vx
eq5 = Eq( ia, i2 + 0.5*vx )
eq6 = Eq( vc - vb, 2*(i3-i2) )                             # relates vb to vc
eq7 = Eq( va, -r1*i1 )
eq8 = Eq( vc, r4*i3 )
ans = solve( [ eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8 ], [ i1, i2, i3, ib, va, vx, vb, vc ] )
for i in ans: i, ans[i].subs( { r1:25, r2:5, r3:4, r4:2, v1:10, ia:10 } )
(vc, -10.0000000000000)
(vb, -20.0000000000000)
(vx, 40.0000000000000)
(va, 50.0000000000000)
(i3, -5.00000000000000)
(i2, -10.0000000000000)
(i1, -2.00000000000000)
```

I'll let you work out where you went wrong with your KVL approach. Reading through those pencil marks on dingy paper isn't my idea of fun.

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! It cleared my mind!

Comment: @PedroSantana Thanks for letting me know! :) It's nice to know if things help, or not. If that's all you need (if you are not waiting for someone else to supply a different approach), then you can select the answer, as well. This saves others effort. But do this ***only*** if you feel you got what you wanted in my answer. Otherwise, do not select it. That will suggest to others that you may want to see a different treatment.